# a4j:support event onkeyup not working with right click copy and paste

Tags: javascript, jsf, dom-events, richfaces

I've tried looking for a list of all the possible events that can be used in the `a4j:support` event attribute. I cant find any reference that lists them, maybe somebody can provide a link?
I'm aware of the obvious ones like `onclick`, `onchange`, etc.

The reason I ask this is that I currently have an input text field. It has the `onkeyup` event attached to it via the `a4j:support` tag. It should enable a text box when the event fires.
The event does not fire when a user right clicks their mouse and pastes content into the field.
Is there an alternative event I could use to ensure this case is managed?

```
<h:inputText id="someName" value="#{myBean.example.exampleName}" maxlength="25" style="width:280px">
    <a4j:support event="onchange" reRender="exampleTab" 
        action="#{myBean.activateTabPanel}" ajaxSingle="true" 
        ignoreDupResponses="true" />
</h:inputText>

<rich:tabPanel id="exampleTab" switchType="server"
    style="width:100%;height:448px;" styleClass="top_tab"
    inactiveTabClass="inactive_tab" activeTabClass="active_tab"
    selectedTab="#{myBean.exampleTabState.selectedTab}">
    <!-- Various stuff in here --->
</rich>
```

## ************ Update ***********##

I actually went with a jQuery solution in the end. Was much cleaner. Code attached for anyone interested.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    
    // Call contructor
    var common = new Site.Common();
    
});


// Constructor
Site.Common = function() {
    
    // Only attach event listener if the element exists on page
    if ( jQuery('input[id$="suggest"]') ) {
        jQuery('input[id$="suggest"]').bind('paste', Site.Common.handleMousePaste.bind(this));
    }

};


// Trigger the keyup event when user uses mouse to paste content info a field('element')
Site.Common.handleMousePaste = function(event) {
        
    // Need to split the id (JSF adds the form name in front of the input field!)
    var idParts = event.target.id.split(':');
    
    // Reformat the id we will pass to jQuery (It does not understand formName:fieldName, need to escape the ':')
    if (idParts.length >= 2) {
        var formattedID = "#" + idParts[0] + "\\:" + idParts[1];
    }
    else {
        var formattedID = "#" + event.target.id;
    }
    
    // Need to put a tiny delay in so the element has time to get the pasted in content.
    setTimeout(function() { jQuery(formattedID).keyup(); }, 10);

};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can detect the paste event in js and activate your function then.

attached is a link that deals with similar problem

[link](http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/572155-how-detect-paste-action-textbox)

in it change what happens after the paste is detected

```
if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 86) //Paste event
   call your function
```

Comment: Is this the only way to achieve this Aba? (Ideally I'd like to avoid writing custom js code).

Comment: @Mcloving you can also detect mouseEvents <very good site: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_mouse.html>. it rely depends on the business constraints concerning page behavior. maybe you should use "onblur" instead of "onchange"?

Comment: Yeah, my panel need to be enabled the moment a user enters something into the input textbox. I'm thinking onchange is the correct option. Am I right in saying onchange should trigger the moment any new text is entered or removed from the input box? Why is is waiting until I tab away from the input box if this is the case?

Comment: @Mcloving .On IE onchange fires only after you are away from the field. it probably would work on firefox. if you want to check for changes than onkeyup might be a good solution for you.

Comment: It currently is using onKeyUp :) The problem is that will not fire when text is pasted in via a right mouse click. After looking at all the possible events I dont think there is one to handle this situation? I'm thinking the e.keycode is the only option?

Comment: @Mcloving wasthe keyCode solution sufficient ?

Comment: -1 The keycode specified is for the 'v' key. So this would call the function even when just typing 'v'. Further down in the link this is brought up.

Comment: @Adam indeed, forgot the ctrl. added to response.

Comment: @AbaDov still not really a "Paste event" as the user could still use insert key or context menu paste, but I've removed my -1.

Comment: @Adam, It all boils down to the amount needed to do it. You can also prevent mouse events from focusing on the element. you can go further and only allow specific keys to be pressed. you should by the way apply a validator before submission\when losing focus. But one should look at it case to case. depending on client requirements and the users.

Comment: @AbaDov I am wholly in agreement. It's tough to say how far you should go to stop the user from putting in incorrect info and validating server side protects from misuse.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard events do not suppose to work when clicking on the mouse (pasting, clicking, etc).
As I understand you searching for a OnChange event but the OnChange is not good for you because 
you need that the event will fire in any input that the input text get.

The solution is to use the new HTML5 OnInput Event. The OnInput event fire in any input e.g. past using
the mouse, typing, pasting using the keyboard, etc.

It also support all the new browsers, I test it on: IE9,IE10,IE11,Chrome,Firefox,Safari and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

The list of possible values for the `event` attribute is not fixed, as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/tlddoc/a4j/support.html):

> Name of JavaScript event property ( onclick, onchange, etc.) of **parent component**, for which we will build AJAX submission code

So basically, it means that you can set in the `event` attribute, any `onXXX` event that is available on the parent component.

---

Regarding your problem, you can eventually duplicate your `<a4j:support event="onkeyup">` with a `<a4j:support event="onchange">`.

Note that if your request is just to enable a text box, maybe you can do that using JavaScript, and not with Ajax call (i.e. using `<a4j:support>`).

Comment: Thanks romaintaz. My request is actually changing a beacking bean value and then enabling a Richfaces tabPanel. Using the 'onchange' event does not seem to be working as I would expect. It only fires when I tab away from the input box, not when I make addition/deletions to the input box. Any ideas? I'll edit original question with some code.